# ERROR: ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported for this operation. Try ALGORITHM=COPY/INPLACE

Tags: mysql

I have used mysqldump to create a table that is 12GB from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0.29. I want to add a column using `ALTER TABLE documents ADD COLUMN meta_data json NULL, algorithm=instant;` in the new table created in 8.0.29. When I run this I keep getting the error `ERROR: ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported for this operation. Try ALGORITHM=COPY/INPLACE`.

When searching Google I can only find information about a bug that should have been fixed in 8.0.14 as can be seen [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227728/error-code-1845-algorithm-instant-is-not-supported-for-this-operation-try-alg) .

I do not have any fulltext index on my table and trying to add the column to the end of the list.

Anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: I tested on 8.0.28 and it works without error. This may be a regression bug, because 8.0.29 has changed some implementation of `algorithm=instant`.

Comment: Same issue 6 months later with v8.0.31 (the same command on the same table worked fine on v8.0.30)

Comment: Same/simular issues here on MySQL/Percona 8.0.33-25 and MySQL/Percona 8.0.30-22.

When simply adding a column onto a table, using ```ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `field` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE```, MySQL reports "#1846 - ALGORITHM=INPLACE is not supported. Reason: INPLACE ADD or DROP of virtual columns cannot be combined with other ALTER TABLE actions."

However, the column isn't virtual at all. In earlier versions of MySQL, this worked like a charm, now it's broken.